# Update a document and upsert a subdocument in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I update an item in the parent document and upsert a subdocument in a single query?

This is my example schema.

```
const ExampleSchema = new Schema({
  user_count: {
    type: String,
    default: 0
  },
  users: [
    {
      id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users",
        unique: true
      },
      action: {
        type: Boolean
      }
    }
  ],

});
```

I am trying to add +1 to user_count and upsert a document to the users array in a single query.

```
const result = await Example.updateOne(
      {
        _id: id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "user_count": user_count++,
          "users.$.id": req.user.id,
          "users.$.action": true
        } 
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

I have tried the above code, but got the following error.

```sh
[0]    'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.',
[0]   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Do you want to push value to Users Array or you just need to update 0 element? Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I want to do both: upsert a user into the array and update the user_count element.  I am using MongoDB 4.0.12 and mongoose 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with mongoose, so I will take for granted that `"user_count": user_count++` works.

For the rest, there are two things that won't work:

- the `$` operator in `"users.$.id": req.user.id,` is known as the positional operator, and that's not what you want, it's used to update a specific element in an array. Further reading here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/
- the `upsert` is about inserting a full document if the `update` does not match anything in the collection. In your case you just want to push an element in the array right?

In this case I guess something like this might work:

```
const result = await Example.updateOne(
      {
        _id: id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "user_count": user_count++
        },
        $addToSet: {
           "users": {
              "id": req.user.id,
              "action": true
           }
        }
      }
    );
```

Please note that `$push` might also do the trick instead of `$addToSet`. But `$addToSet` takes care of keeping stuff unique in your array.

Comment: I tried this code but it keeps on adding a new element to the users array.  I would like to upsert (insert only if users.id does not exist)

Comment: Then no luck to do this in one query :/ The positional operator is indeed the way to go to update the array, but you need to apply a filter on `users.id` (alongside the `_id: id`. But this will NOT let you push an element inside the array if not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {"user_count": user_count++},$addToSet: {"users": {"id": req.user.id,"action": true}}}, {returnOriginal:false}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but it keeps on adding a new element to the users array. I would like to upsert (insert only if users.id does not exist)